# Which is the best Certification course offered in Joomla for Professional Web Designing and development?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I wanted to know which is the best Certification course which gives a proper knowledge about Joomla! in and out .

I wanted to pursue a career in Joomla! as Professional Web Designer and Developer,
Please suggest me some Certifications .
Thank you !

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't bother. Just take some classes, use the tool, make stuff with it and learn. To me certifications only show one thing: You can read and answer the questions given to you. It doesn't always show that you can figure out things you didn't know before hand, or that you're just good at putting things together. I suspect I'd fail a cert test right now if I didn't study up all the crap in it, yet I spend all day, every day in Joomla.

Comment: @BrianPeat I am choosing Certifications to increase my skills as a developer.According to me certifications provide a better to get better projects for development ! correct me if am wrong!

Comment: @SrinathNaidu - Certifications do not increase your skills as a developer. Researching and practice increases your skills. Besides, the majority of exams these days are multiple choice and therefore you have the answer already there. You just need to guess which one it is. If you are able to answer in-depth questions simply by writing them, then I would consider that more impressive as it shows one has a better understanding.

Comment: I think you're confusing certifications with courses. Take some courses, buy a book but most of all just use joomla and learn by using it.

Comment: A lot of certification courses are the sort of thing that are sold on Groupon - i.e. a rip off.

Comment: @BrianPeat I Totally get your point 
Can you please suggest some of the good books or tutorials apart from joomla.org to learn from !

Comment: I know that Lynda.com has some tutorials, and there are lots of books out there. Honestly for me I just started building sites and I googled for answers when I got stuck. Now that we have this StackExchange, there's a good place to get answers.I suspect any of the blue Joomla Press books you can find on amazon would be good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Certifications prove nothing as @Brian has already mentioned. I have absolutely zero qualifications in computer science or development and believe it or not, I actually failed I.T (computers) at A-level when I was 18, yet I'm still a full time developer and got where I am from experience.

Showing on paper that you can answer +-40 questions about a CMS doesn't compete against a full portfolio of bespoke websites with custom designs and extensions, especially when you're self taught.

I'm not entirely sure if you're new to just Joomla or new to the whole development world, however if you are new to development in general, one piece of advice I will give is, don't simply stick to Joomla development. Always go back to the root which is what Joomla is written in. **PHP**

Comment: Totally agree with Brian and Lodder. However Joomla "is cooking" something relative... you can follow them at their fb page: https://www.facebook.com/joomlacertificationprogram

Answer (score 5):

There are also currently no official Joomla certifications.  There is a Certification Team that is working on a set of certifications with the help of the community.  They are crafting the exams and subject matter based on real world experience by real world developers.

We agree as a team that there are reasons to have a certification.  Certainly, those of us who work on the bespoke websites don't need them.  However, it might be a nice way of weeding out candidates for corporate site administration and so forth.

Really, it's a fine line and the team is trying to walk it.

Answer (score 4):

Your work will be far better evidence of your skills than a certificate. Anyone can buy a certificate saying they can do anything at all, making them worthless.

Practice your skills by making sites, learning from what you see on the web and make something epic. I'd put money on the fact that none of the superstar web designers in the world today have a certificate even vaguely related to web design.

Answer (score 3):

Although this isn't a certification program, if you are serious about making a living Joomla!ng then I highly recommend Joomla [programmer] by Mark Dexter and Louis Landry

That book will give you a strong foundation on how J! works. There is also a new book that is targeted at J!3.x, but I haven't read it yet, so I cannot make A recommendation for it.

You might also benefit from reading Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the heart of software (Eric Evans) and  Clean Code (Robert C. Martin)

These there books combined will put you ahead of at least half the J! Completion out there at the moment.

I hope this helps.

Comment: These there = These three;

Answer (score 0):

There has been a team working on an official certification path for Joomla.  You can learn more about it at https://certification.joomla.org/administrator-exam

Answer (score 0):

You can check more info about the ***Official Joomla! Certification Program*** and available
 dates in: https://certification.joomla.org

At the time of this post*(May 2016)* these are the Certifications planned:

- Joomla! Administrator
- Joomla! Template
- Joomla! Developer

Regards.

---

**2020 Update**

Today the available certification is called "**Joomla! Administrator Exam**"

Find a learaning guide with the topics covered here: [**Learning Guide**](https://certification.joomla.org/exams/administrator-learning-guide)

These topic include:

- Joomla! Architecture
- Website Structure
- Installation
- Security and Maintenance
- Upgrading System
- Language Management
- Content Management
- Menu Management
- User Management
- Extension Management
- Miscellaneaus Tasks